# Can BLE in Android use custom key for encryption

Tags: android, security, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Android device as Peripheral and a Cypress BLE chip as the Central. Is it possible to hardcode the 128 bit encryption key in both of them and use it for encryption? If yes could you please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, not for use by the built-in encryption + authentication in the BLE protocol. You can however do your own encryption on the application level.